# how to format / execute post content and shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">


        <?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

            endwhile; endif; 
        ?>      


    </div>
```

As I understand, the above code will execute both content and shortcode. But I want to format first the page content before displaying it in the page. What's the best way to do this? Tia.

**UPDATE:**

Should have included the content page:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content();
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

If I understand correctly, `the_content` renders both page text / contents including the shortcode. What I'm trying to do is render the text / page contents separately. I wanted to add styling to text / page contents and shortcode separately.

Comment: All that code does is include content-page.php for each post. How the post is rendered depends on what's in that file. That being said, your question doesn't make a lot of sense. What does "format first the page content" even mean?

Comment: @jacob peattie I updated my question, should be making a lot of sense now. :)

Comment: It still doesn't really make sense hat you're trying to do. Shortcodes are added as part of the content, so how would they be separate? And why can't you just use CSS like normal to style them differently?

Comment: http://www.eightelms.co.uk/collections/ this is the page I'm working. As you can see, the slider and text that reads 'Introduction..' are overlapping. That's why I'm asking how to format or render them separately.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `the_content()` not rendering things 'separately'. It's because of the way the slideshow is styled. You should check with the plugin developer what you can do. Other than that you can just use normal CSS to make any changes you need. The issue isn't directly related to WordPress or your template.